# template non-type parameter: check condition at compile-time

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I want to use template non-type parameter to do automatic branching of the code at compile time. I.e. something like:

```
template<std::size_t TDimension>
class A
{
public:
    A()
    {}

    ~A()
    {}

    void print()
    {
        if(TDimension == 3)
            std::cout << "My dimension is 3" << std::endl;
        else if(TDimension == 2)
            std::cout << "My dimension is 2" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

The code above branch the code in run-time. The question is: how can I enable it in compile-time to improve the performance?

Comment: Have you measured this code's performance? No? Then how will you know if you improved the performance when you change it? You cannot improve without something to improve upon. (Don't worry, the compiler has done the optimisation for you.)

Comment: Constant expression and dead-branch elimination are really low hanging optimization fruit.  There are reasons to want a true compile-time branch, but they typically involve "the other branch won't even compile if the parameter is wrong".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since both `TDimension` and the values you compare it with are constant, the compiler *should* only generate one branch of the `if` with no run-time comparison, as long as you enable optimisation.

To be sure, you could explicitly specialise instead:

```
template<std::size_t TDimension>
class A
{
public:
    void print() {}
    // or void print(); to give an error for an handled value
};

template <> void A<3>::print() {std::cout << "My dimension is 3" << std::endl;}
template <> void A<2>::print() {std::cout << "My dimension is 2" << std::endl;}
```

Comment: Your code does not give a damn what the stupid programmer tells it - it's always in the third dimension ;)

Comment: Perfect. That's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that comes across this question now that we are blessed with C++17: you could avoid using template specializations by using `if constexpr`, should it be more pleasing to your eyes:

```
void print()
{
    if constexpr(TDimension == 3)
        std::cout << "My dimension is 3" << std::endl;
    else if constexpr(TDimension == 2)
        std::cout << "My dimension is 2" << std::endl;
}
```